# Automatically clicking through public wifi entrance pages

Tags: wireless-networking, android

Some public wifi networks don't let me use HTTP before I open a browser and click through a page, usually on a button labelled "Agree to conditions" (is there a name for these pages?) Is there an app for Android that does this automatically as soon as the device connects to the network, at least for networks I already know?

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic here; as well, this belongs on the android site, where you'll likely get more help anyways

Comment: Already asked and answered there: [Auto login to wifi networks](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9327) , [Free Wi-Fi network: how to autoaccept (robotic click) wifi policy web page?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28515) , [Can I automatically log in to open WiFi that requires web login/password?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/823)

Answer (score 2):

he [captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) technique forces an HTTP client on a network to see a special web page (usually for authentication purposes) before using the Internet normally. A captive portal turns a Web browser into an authentication device.

Hope [WIFI Web Login](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidyou.wifiloginnew&hl=en) is what you are looking for.

Comment: It looks like the answer. I'll try it out tomorrow.